# Error while including inkscape image in tex file

Tags: graphics, diagrams, inkscape

I am using the Tex Live 2013/Debian on my Ubuntu 14.04

I exported an image as PDF in Inkscape (and checked the PDF+Latex option). To include the image in my latex file, I used the following command

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{2.pdf_tex}
\caption{Flowchart describing our approach.}
\end{figure}
```

However, on building the .tex in TexMaker, I get the following error

```
(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Being not familiar with `inkscape` exporting facilities I can't say something about that, but do you have a `\usepackage{xcolor}` statement in the preamble of your `.tex` file?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks. It worked. You can add this as answer. Also, now I feel so dumb about asking such a trivial question.

Comment: In order to 'close' this question I will add it as answer, but do not mind about asking at all, especially for beginners of `\LaTeX`, we all forgot (and do forget even nowadays) `\usepackage` commands when being new to `\LaTeX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `inkscape` can export figures as `.tex` file, it has to put all relevant drawing information as `\LaTeX` commands, such it needs additional packages as `xcolor` etc.

Since this exported figure can be included basically anywhere inside of a document via `\input`, the relevant packages must be loaded of course in the preamble of the document, not in the document body.

This particular question could be solved by stating

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

For other `inkscape` exports, there might be more `\usepackage` - commands necessary, sometimes even with options.